# T-SQL XML: <eof> encountered when trying to query child nodes by wildcard

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, nodes

We have an in-house piece of software that works with loosely-defined XML files. I'm trying to extract the child nodes from this step in T-SQL. I'm able to extract the parent node, but I keep getting <eof> syntax errors whenever I query the children.

The XML file looks roughly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <steps>
    <step>
      <steptypeX attribute="somevalue">
        <child1>Value</child1>
        <child2>Value</child2>
      </steptypeX>
    </step>
  </steps>
</root>
```

I'm using the following T-SQL:

```
select
doc.col.query('/child*') --If I use '.' or '*' here I can get the children as XML, but I want the values contained within the nodes on separate rows
from @xmldoc.nodes('/root/steps/step/steptypeX') doc(col)
where doc.col.value('@attribute', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'somevalue'
```

The error message I'm getting is not clear:

```
XQuery [query()]: Syntax error near '<eof>'
```

As far as I can tell, the nodes do exist and I haven't left any XQuery instructions with trailing slashes. I can't really tell what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You need to remove this line from your xml - `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. Your query is perfectly working in my system once i have remove that line.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I just tried this but it didn't work for me - still getting the same <eof> error with or without the XML declaration

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention correctly you can use `child::*`:

```
DECLARE @xmldoc XML =
N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <steps>
    <step>
      <steptypeX attribute="somevalue">
        <child1>Value</child1>
        <child2>Value</child2>
      </steptypeX>
    </step>
  </steps>
  </root>';

SELECT
   doc.col.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xmldoc.nodes('/root/steps/step/steptypeX/child::*') doc(col)
WHERE doc.col.value('../@attribute', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'somevalue';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414162)**</kbd>

Comment: That seems to be what I want! I don't really understand why I would have to use the /child:: instruction in the nodes() function and go back up for the WHERE clause rather than finding the parent node and selecting the children though

Comment: @Gargravarr The point is your child elements from `/root/steps/step/steptypeX/` has different names (child1 and child2). Using `child::*` you can select them. But in where you are one step deeper in hierarchy so you need to return to parent node to validate attribute value.